# Was this the right call?

Tags: league-of-legends

I played as ADC and the supp was afk from the beginning so I played 1v2 bot lane. They zoned my pretty hard, denying me of CS and EXP.  Jungler was an Udyr. I called him numerous times and even though there were instances where he was full hp near me he never came and just keep on farming in the jungle. I feel like we could have done a play because I had to go back and had some (minor) item advantages over them. Furthermore they were at our tower all the time.

I do have to mention that he had a feral flare to stack and that he did 2 very early solo dragons. Late game he played awful because he just chased after kills in the fog of war and got himself killed.

Setting aside my frustration of not receiving any help at all, was his decision of leaving me alone and farm in the jungle the right one for the team?

Comment: The fact that you were 1v2 not getting farm and experience is the most important point here. Likely you were under-leveled. In this situation, it would've been very risky for Udyr to gank. If he did gank, it could've caused both of you to die; which would've been worse than leaving you alone. That being said, I think it is likely that he gave up due to the man disadvantage, and he may not have been playing to his full team potential - instead preferring to go for solo glory.

Comment: Hopefully we don't get "was this the right call?" questions for every scenario in summoners rift :)

Answer (score 2):

This really depends. A good question to ask yourself in situations like this is: Would it make any difference for **the Team** if he ganked more often?

In the end, it can be really frustrating to lose a lane but a lost lane isn't a lost game. Sometimes a jungler prefers to farm or gank other lanes.

Personally I can see some reasons why Udyr was Farming/Ganking other lanes:

**The Lategame Factor**
Udyr is a lategame beast. He's unkillable, 2shots squishies and is one of the greatest duelists in the game. He also is one of the or the fastest jungler in the game and farm is more secure than ganks.

**The 2v1 ADC Factor**
A 2v1 botlane is really frustrating and it's usually lost unless you play against an ultra passive lane (Janna,Soraka) but even then it's rather hard to keep up with the enemy ADC. Also in the current meta ADCs aren't as strong as they used to be. To Carry a game alone as ADC you still need a lot of feed and maybe Udyr saw that you tried to play rather passively. Another thing to think about is: Would it have made a huge difference if you got 1 or 2 kills? As ADC you really need to be ultra fed to fight an ADC and supporter in early stages of the game.

**The inability to gank Factor**
Well maybe he just couldn't gank with you. Udyrs ganks are most effective if you already have some sort of cc. His gapcloser is just a movementspeed buff and he can be kited really easily. And in a 2v2 with jungler + ADC against a 2v2 with support + ADC, the supp, ADC comp will usually win. Supporters are designed to fight in 2v2 situations, Junglers are designed to completely devastate enemies when they are outnumbered.

**The Junglers fault factor**
Maybe he just didn't know what to do. I mean it's really impossible to always make the right decisions. People wouldn't lose games if they always did the right thing. There are infinite amount of possible situations and each of them requires a different reaction. The best players in the world make mistakes. Also since it was a 4v5 maybe he was just totally overwhelmed by the situation.

So was his decision the right one? I don't know. Most likely it wasn't. There are an infinite amount of situation, each with an infinite amount of "right" solutions. To answer this definitely you'd have to describe every single detail of the game. But these points above can explain some reasons why he **thought** it would be the right decision. People usually don't want to make mistakes but they are inevitable.

Comment: I actually think I agree with his decision (See my comment above) - as it is very risky to gank a lane that is losing in lvls and numbers (1v2). That being said, if I were the jungler, I probably would've helped under tower. Either way, my opinion aside, the rest of your answer is absolutely correct. Especially the fact that Udyr isn't really a gank heavy jungler. +1